# How to receive className with ServerSideRender of Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress, server-side-rendering, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to render a block from PHP with ServerSideRender as follows:

js file:

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { ServerSideRender } = wp.components;

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import icons from './../../utils/icons';

registerBlockType( 'name/blockname', {
  title: __( 'blockname' ),
  description: __( 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.' ),
  keywords: [ __( 'recent post' ) ],
  icon: icons.block,
  category: 'xyz',

  edit: ( props ) => {
    const {
      className,
      attributes,
    } = props;

    return (
      <ServerSideRender
        block="name/blockname"
        attributes={ attributes }
        className={ className }
      />
    );
  },

  save: () => {
    return null;
  },
} );
```

php file:

```php
register_block_type( '.../blockname', array(
   'attributes'      => array(
      'className'    => array(
         'type'      => 'string',
      ),
   ),
   'render_callback' => 'render_block',
) );

function render_block( $attr, $content ) {
    return 'txt';
}
```

Render:

```
   <div>txt</div>
```

Expected:

```
   <div class="wp-block-name-blockname">txt</div>
```

Everything seems to work correctly but the div with the class name is not being rendered.

Any suggestion to fix this? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your `render_block` function to:

```
function render_block( $attr, $content ) {
  return sprintf(
    '<div class="wp-block-name-blockname %1$s">txt</div>',
    esc_attr( $attr['className'] )
  );
}
```

Also see [the official tutorial of creating dynamic blocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/).

Answer (score 0):

Getting default attributes from the argument passed to `render_callback` is not supported. There is an open issue here: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13811. You have to programmatically set `className` per the example. Included below:

```
function block_classes( $name, $attributes = array() ) {
    $classes = array( 'wp-block-' . $name );
    if ( isset( $attributes['align'] ) && $attributes['align'] ) {
        array_push( $classes, 'align' . $attributes['align'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $attributes['className'] ) && $attributes['className'] ) {
        array_push( $classes, $attributes['className'] );
    }
    return implode(  ' ', $classes );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [get_block_wrapper_attributes()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_block_wrapper_attributes/) function.

This function returns a string of HTML attributes.

```
<div <?php echo get_block_wrapper_attributes(); ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the additional classes you need to the function like so:

```
    get_block_wrapper_attributes( [ 'class' => 'container-wide title-main' ] );
    /** returns: `class="container-wide title-main wp-block-my-block"` **/
```

Seems a bit odd that it doesn't just return a string of classes, however there are other attributes it could return, that's why it's done like this.
Think of it as an equivalent to `getBlockProps()`